# C- Ncurses, Window not displaying / printing

Tags: c, ncurses

Ive tried looking for a solution, i just don't know why the window is not displaying. The code is fairly simple and straight forward. Why is this the case? I asked a similar question before but know one seems to have been able to provide the right answer, so I made it a bit simpilar and only included the important stuff.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    initscr();
    WINDOW* win;
    int height = 10;
    int width = 40;
    int srtheight = 1;
    int srtwidth = 0;
    win = newwin(height, width, srtheight ,srtwidth);
    mvwprintw(win, height/2,width/2,"First line");
    wrefresh(win);
    getch();
    delwin(win);
    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to call refresh.

Basically, you did call refresh on your newly create window, but you forgot to refresh the parent window, so it never redrew.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW* my_win;
    int height = 10;
    int width = 40;
    int srtheight = 1;
    int srtwidth = 1;
    initscr();
    printw("first"); // added for relative positioning
    refresh();  //  need to draw the root window
                //  without this, apparently the children never draw
    my_win = newwin(height, width, 5, 5);
    box(my_win, 0, 0);  // added for easy viewing
    mvwprintw(my_win, height/2,width/2,"First line");
    wrefresh(my_win);
    getch();
    delwin(my_win);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

gives the windows as you expected.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `getch` refreshes the standard window `stdscr`, overwriting the refresh which was done for `win` on the previous line.  If you had called `wgetch(win)` rather than those two lines, it would have worked.

Like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    initscr();
    WINDOW* win;
    int height = 10;
    int width = 40;
    int srtheight = 1;
    int srtwidth = 0;
    win = newwin(height, width, srtheight ,srtwidth);
    mvwprintw(win, height/2,width/2,"First line");
    /* wrefresh(win); */
    wgetch(win);
    delwin(win);
    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

Further reading:

- [Reading characters](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters), e.g., `wgetch`

Answer (score 1):

You need a call to `refresh()` after `newwin()`:

```
win = newwin(height, width, srtheight ,srtwidth);
refresh(); // <<<
mvwprintw(win, height/2,width/2,"First line");
```

Comment: I think it's calling `refresh()` after `initscr()` that's the key part, rather than necessarily after `newwin()`...

Comment: Ok, so you beat me to it (byt a few minutes); but, it seems that if you at least refresh() the root window once, then wrefresh(...) of children work without further need to refresh() the parent.