# Ncurses wrefresh not showing window borders

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I am experimenting with some C++ using ncurses and am having trouble showing the window borders, but am having trouble with the following programs.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 5)
    {
        printf("not enough arguments\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    int height = atoi(argv[1]); 
    int width = atoi(argv[2]); 
    int y = atoi(argv[3]);
    int x = atoi(argv[4]); 

    initscr(); 
    WINDOW *win = newwin(height, width, y, x);  
    box(win, 0, 0); 
    wrefresh(win); 

    int py, px; 
    getparyx(win, py, px); 
    mvprintw(LINES-2, 0, "getparyx: (%d, %d)", py, px); 

    int by, bx; 
    getbegyx(win, by, bx); 
    mvprintw(LINES-1, 0, "getbegyx: (%d, %d)", by, bx); 


    getch(); 
    delwin(win); 
    endwin(); 
}
```

In the program above I draw the border using `box` and refresh using `wrefresh`, but it doesn't show anything. The other stuff that I print to `stdscr`, however, does show.

In another program however I was able to get the border working.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() 
{
    const int height = 6, width = 8; 

    WINDOW *win; 
    int starty, startx; 
    int ch; 

    initscr(); 
    cbreak(); 
    noecho(); 
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE); 

    starty = (LINES - height) / 2; 
    startx = (COLS - width) / 2; 
    win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx); 
    box(win, 0, 0); 
    wrefresh(win); 

    while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1)) 
    {
        wborder(win, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '); 
        wrefresh(win); 
        delwin(win); 
        switch(ch) 
        {
            case KEY_UP: 
                win = newwin(height, width, --starty, startx);                 
                break; 
            case KEY_DOWN:
                win = newwin(height, width, ++starty, startx); 
                break; 
            case KEY_LEFT: 
                win = newwin(height, width, starty, --startx); 
                break; 
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                win = newwin(height, width, starty, ++startx); 
                break; 
        }
        move(starty + (height / 2) - 1, startx + (width / 2) - 1); 
        box(win, 0, 0); 
        wrefresh(win); 
    }

    delwin(win); 
    endwin(); 
}
```

The thing is that the border only appears in the loop. In other words the border does not start to show until I press buttons, meaning the initial `wrefresh` did not work.

After doing some research I [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642580/c-ncurses-window-not-displaying-printing) thread which suggested to call `refresh` after `initscr` (or at least before `wrefresh()`) but that did not work. So what am I missing that the border does not show in the first program?

Comment: regarding; `printf("not enough arguments\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2)  this error message fails to tell the user (and us) what the list of arguments should be.  Suggest starting with `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s  <list of arguments, separated by spaces>\n". argv[0] );`

Comment: The arguments are supposed to be height, width, y, and x. I'm pretty sure that's obvious. I did not write a proper error message because I'm just testing. But thank you for showing me the proper way to report errors. I knew about `stderr` before but did not know how to properly use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my tests, that initial `refresh()` is certainly what is missing.  I checked some old code I wrote, and it indeed calls `refresh()` as part of the ncurses initialisation.  Adding this to your code made it work for me.  A lot of the curses documentation is still constrained to books, it never really made it onto the web.

```
initscr();
refresh();          // <-- HERE

WINDOW *win = newwin( height, width, y, x );  
box( win, 0, 0 );
wrefresh(win);
```

I don't think the windowing model is fully initialised until after that first `refresh()` is called.  But I could not find any documentation on *exactly* why that would be the case.

So not much detail in this answer, sorry...  but I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked. Perhaps I spelt `refresh` wrong and for some reason C decided not to complain about it. I'm working off of man pages and a guide that was made in 2005 so you could imagine how frustrating this was.

Comment: I also think I read somewhere that `getch` refreshes the screen so maybe that is why the latter code works.

Answer (score 1):

The manual pages answer the question:

- [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr)

> initscr also causes the first call to  refresh(3x)
> to  clear  the  screen.

- [`getch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the
> last call to wrefresh, wrefresh will be called before another character
> is read.

- The `initscr` (clear) and the `mvprintw` calls update `stdscr`, which is finally ***refreshed*** when you call `getch`.  `stdscr` is a window, and as noted in the discussion of [`wrefresh`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-wnoutrefresh_doupdate), the physical screen is updated in the order that refreshes are applied (that is, it overlaps with the other window, and if you want the other window to appear, you should refresh `stdscr` first, to handle the clearing operation).